# D3 JS Circle with Text

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to modify a bubble chart (https://usabilityetc.github.io/d3-country-bubble-chart/demo/) to include some text on top of each circle, i've understand the text can't be attached to the circle itself so i've been trying various things to get it working but don't have a lot of JS experience.

Here is a link to the Plnkr project: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/a4r9hxN9JhQxSPDC
In the browser console i can see the text is being bound to the circle but i'm not sure if this is right as nothing appears on the page.  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fLf5.png)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is as follows. You replace circles with groups (`g` elements). Circle coordinates (`cx` and `cy`) become group translation (`.attr('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')')`). Then you append `circle` and `text` to the group.

Comment: Thanks but i'm not sure how to use that as the sections where it draws and updates the circles are within functions, if i try and add anything after or within those functions it still doesn't work.